# Congruence mod k

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to evaluate the following scenario:

$$7^b \equiv 9\pmod {17}$$

Find the smallest value for b in which the equivalence holds true.

I know that we can rewrite this as :

$$17 \mid (7^b - 9)$$

But I'm not sure how to continue, could anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: As you take powers of 7, reduce mod 17 at each step.

Comment: So am I supposed to just keep taking powers of 7?

Comment: Yes, but you use the reduced (mod 17) value to compute the next power at each step.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate, reducing modulo $17$ each time. And I like to use negative numbers when they make the arithmetic simpler.

We have $7^2\equiv -2$, and therefore $7^3\equiv -14\equiv 3$. Now do you see it's almost over?

**Remark:** There *is* general theory. If you are interested, please look at Wikipedia, [Discrete Logarithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) But the general theory in this case would involve much more work than the modified brute force approach that we took.